# Typescript import doesnt work because class is in dist folder

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsc

I have created an npm library in typescript which has 2 clasess with the following structure:

```
ROOT
| index.ts
| /models
  | model.ts
```

Then I publish the lib and import model class into another project like this:

```
import ModelClass from '@someorg/lib-name/models/ModelClass'
```

All goes well untill I compile this, and the javascript compiled version starts looking on to the "dist" folder for the Model class and it cant find it. I then go to the dist folder and modify the import as:

```
const modelClass_1 = require('@someorg/lib-name/dist/models/ModelClass'
```

and it works, how can I do so I don't have to put in the /dist manually every time?

Comment: You need to compile your module and publish only the compiled dist folder to npm.

Comment: @hyperdrive is correct. But, alternatively, you can change your `"main"` to `"dist/index"`